# Problems building WSC jar files from SalesForce enterprise WSDL

Tags: compilation, wsdl, salesforce, wsc

As specified in [these instructions](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Introduction_to_the_Force.com_Web_Services_Connector), I downloaded my organization's `enterprise.wsdl` file, downloaded `wsc-23.jar` from the [Web Services Connector downloads page](http://code.google.com/p/sfdc-wsc/downloads/list), and ran the following command from the directory containing the two downloaded files:

```
java -classpath wsc-23.jar com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc enterprise.wsdl enterprise.jar
```

which generated this output:

```
[WSC23][wsdlc.run:348]Created temp dir: C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Temp\wsd
lc-temp-215798849-dir
[WSC23][wsdlc.<init>:110]Generating Java files from schema ...
[WSC23][wsdlc.<init>:110]Generated 290 java files.
[WSC23][wsdlc.compileTypes:298]Compiling to target default...
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class RecordType
  location: package com.sforce.soap.enterprise.sobject
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class RecordType
  location: package com.sforce.soap.enterprise.sobject
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class RecordType
  location: package com.sforce.soap.enterprise.sobject
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class RecordType
  location: package com.sforce.soap.enterprise.sobject
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class RecordType
  location: package com.sforce.soap.enterprise.sobject
Error: Compilation failed
```

Why is class `RecordType` causing compilation to fail?

Comment: Can you confirm you have `<complexType name="RecordType">...</complexType>` in your WSDL? I'm thinking it might be a visibility issue where the other objects are looking up to RecordType, but you don't have RecordType itself in your WSDL.

Comment: @ryanbrainard No, that complex type does not exist in the WSDL.  So did SalesForce generate a bad WSDL for my organization?

Comment: It's possible. I just tried removing the `<complexType name="RecordType">...</complexType>` from element from my WSDL and reproduced the same issue. Are you using Professional Edition, perhaps? There might be a bug that isn't special casing PE's lack of record types?? I'd recommend filing an issue with SFDC Support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround to the issue we discussed in comments above, try manually adding the `RecordType` complex type to your WSDL. Here is what it should look like:

```
<complexType name="RecordType">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="ens:sObject">
            <sequence>
            <element name="BusinessProcessId" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:ID"/>
            <element name="CreatedBy" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ens:User"/>
            <element name="CreatedById" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:ID"/>
            <element name="CreatedDate" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
            <element name="Description" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
            <element name="DeveloperName" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
            <element name="IsActive" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:boolean"/>
            <element name="IsPersonType" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:boolean"/>
            <element name="LastModifiedBy" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ens:User"/>
            <element name="LastModifiedById" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:ID"/>
            <element name="LastModifiedDate" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
            <element name="Localization" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult"/>
            <element name="Name" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
            <element name="NamespacePrefix" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
            <element name="SobjectType" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
            <element name="SystemModstamp" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
            </sequence>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

As I mentioned above, this sounds like a bug in the WSDL generation, so I'd recommend filing a ticket with SFDC Support as well.

Comment: I am working with SFDC to get this resolved, and your workaround worked for the time being.  Thanks!